# Ubuntu 21.10: Wacom tablet not longer working in dual monitor setup

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, tablet, 21.10, wacom

Since the Ubuntu 21.04 -> 21.10 upgrade my Wacom tablet is either stuck on my primary or secondary monitor. No matter what I change in the Wacom preferences dialog:

[image]

the stylus area will not stretch over both monitors simultaneously where the cursor would be able to move from freely from one to the other. This has never been an issue before and it's really a pain.

Hardware:

- Lenovo laptop T460p
- Wacom Intuos PT M 2 Pen

These are the settings according to xsetwacom:

```
$ xsetwacom  --list
Wacom Intuos PT M 2 Pen stylus          id: 13  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos PT M 2 Finger touch        id: 14  type: TOUCH     
Wacom Intuos PT M 2 Pad pad             id: 15  type: PAD       

$ xsetwacom get 13 all
Option "Area" "0 0 21600 13500"
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Option "DebugLevel" "0"
Option "CommonDBG" "0"
Option "Suppress" "2"
Option "RawSample" "4"
Option "PressCurve" "0 0 100 100"
Option "Mode" "Absolute"
Option "TPCButton" "off"
Option "Touch" "off"
Property 'Wacom Hardware Touch Switch' does not exist on device.
Option "Gesture" "off"
Option "ZoomDistance" "0"
Option "ScrollDistance" "0"
Option "TapTime" "250"
Option "CursorProx" "30"
Option "Rotate" "none"
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Option "Threshold" "26"
Option "Serial" "0"
Option "PressureRecalibration" "on"
Option "PanScrollThreshold" "1300"

$ xrandr
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+2560+223 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   2560x1440     60.00 +  48.00    59.95
   1920x1440     60.00
   1856x1392     60.01
   1792x1344     60.01
   2048x1152     59.90    59.91
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95
   1920x1080     59.97    59.96    59.93*
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88
   1600x1024     60.17
   1400x1050     59.98
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1280x960      60.00
   1440x810      60.00    59.97
   1368x768      59.88    59.85
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91
   1152x864      60.00
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74
   1024x768      60.04    60.00
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.05
   896x672       60.01
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
   960x600       59.93    60.00
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
   840x525       60.01    59.88
   864x486       59.92    59.57
   800x512       60.17
   700x525       59.98
   800x450       59.95    59.82
   640x512       60.02
   720x450       59.89
   700x450       59.96    59.88
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x405       59.51    58.99
   684x384       59.88    59.85
   680x384       59.80    59.96
   640x400       59.88    59.98
   576x432       60.06
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
   512x384       60.00
   512x288       60.00    59.92
   480x270       59.63    59.82
   400x300       60.32    56.34
   432x243       59.92    59.57
   320x240       60.05
   360x202       59.51    59.13
   320x180       59.84    59.32
DP-2 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 526mm x 296mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+  74.97
   1920x1200     59.88
   1920x1080     74.97    60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1680x1050     59.88
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1366x768      59.79
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   832x624       74.55
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
```

I've tried several display drivers from Nvidia and Nouveau to no avail. Also I can't find anybody with similar issues online. Am I the only one? Please let me know if you have an idea how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the related bug report at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/1568

I've been able to temporarily fix the problem by running:

```
xinput set-prop 13 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```